# How do I get my DAX measure "Calculate" to consider slicer selections?

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a simple measure, to find the items (products) per order - so, on average a box contains 2.5 items.

```
divide(
SUM('SubOrders'[Items in Packet]), 
DISTINCTCOUNT('SubOrders'[SubOrderID]))
```

This works fine. What I want to do is have the above consider the slicer selections from some related tables.

Relationships are all one-to-many, as below:

[image]

My failed attempt looked like this:

```
=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'SubOrders'[Items in Packet] ) / DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'SubOrders'[SubOrderID] ),
    ALLSELECTED ( Warehouse[Warehouse] ),
    ALLSELECTED ( SubOrderStatus[SubOrderStatus] ),
    ALLSELECTED ( Store[Store] )
)
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you're using a measure and not a calculated column?

Comment: I think it must have been a syntax error, re-wrote it as per RADO's edit and it worked, thanks